# Valid header names

Tags: c++, c

I can't understand correctly what does they mean in the following article:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1566.htm

> It is interesting to note that C89 explicitly allowed only letters in
>   header and include file names. C++ added underscores, and C99 added
>   digits. Probably both standards should allow both.

I found the following statements in all C and C++ standards:

**ISO/IEC 9899:1990**

> ```
> 6.1.7 Header names
>
> Syntax
> 1 header-name:
> < h-char-sequence >
> " q-char-sequence "
> h-char-sequence:
> h-char
> h-char-sequence h-char
> h-char:
> any member of the source character set except
> the new-line character and >
> q-char-sequence:
> q-char
> q-char-sequence q-char
> q-char:
> any member of the source character set except
> the new-line character and "
> ```

**ISO/IEC 9899:1990**

> ```
> 5.2.1 Character sets
>
> ...
>
> Both the basic source and basic execution character sets shall have the following
> members: the 26 uppercase letters of the Latin alphabet
>
> A B C D E F G H I J K L M
> N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
>
> the 26 lowercase letters of the Latin alphabet
>
> a b c d e f g h i j k l m
> n o p q r s t u v w x y z
>
> the 10 decimal digits
>
> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
>
> the following 29 graphic characters
>
> ! " # % & ' ( ) * + , — . / :
> ; < = > ? [ \ ] ^ _ { | } ~
> ```

For example, i see underscore and digits even in C89 / C90.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: @Synxis Why in the article author said that digits were only added in C99 and underscore character in C++, while i see it even in C89 / C90.

Comment: The problem the author sees is that the new standards have added headers like `iso646.h` and `type_traits` even though the C89 preprocessor isn't formally required to work with those names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's referring to this:

> There shall be an implementation-defined mapping between the delimited
>   sequence and the external source file name.  The implementation shall
>   provide unique mappings for sequences consisting of one or more
>   letters (as defined in $2.2.1) followed by a period (.)  and a single
>   letter.  The implementation may ignore the distinctions  of
>   alphabetical case and restrict the mapping to six significant
>   characters before the period.

(C89)

This is the C99 version:

> The implementation shall provide unique mappings for sequences
>   consisting of one or more letters or digits (as deﬁned in 5.2.1)
>   followed by a period (.) and a single letter. The ﬁrst character shall
>   be a letter. The implementation may ignore the distinctions of
>   alphabetical case and restrict the mapping to eight signiﬁcant
>   characters before the period.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So, implementation can fail to compile or incorrectly compile code with #include "file_1.h" and #include "file_2.h" in C89 / C90, right?

Comment: @NikitaTrophimov - it would seem so. It seems a bit contradictory though.